# Count to 80, skipping every 5th number in a range of 100 numbers

Tags: php, actionscript, range, skip, ceil

I'm working on a quiz with 80 numbered questions. After every 4 questions there will be an unnumbered 5th bonusquestion. These 100 questions have index-numbers (1-100) in a database table. Maybe it'd have been more logical to use a separate table for the bonusquestions, but the client wants the questions in one table in that order.

I don't want to display the bonusquestion index-numbers in the interface of the quiz, therefore i need to skip every 5th index-number from the range of 100 questions.

I did manage to make a simple calculation which works well when i check it in a loop, but somehow i feel it's a rather dirty solution (ceil). Is there any way of writing this code in a neater or more logical way?

**ActionScript:**

```
for (var i:Number = 1; i < 101; i++) {
    var displayIndex:Number = Math.ceil((i/5) * 4);
    trace("i:" + i + " / " + displayIndex);
}
```

**PHP:**

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 101; $i++) {
    echo "i: " . $i . " / displayIndex: " . (ceil(($i/5) * 4) . "<br>");
}
```

**Edit:**
Let me try to visualize this

```
index-number =  1 -> display-number =  1
index-number =  2 -> display-number =  2
index-number =  3 -> display-number =  3
index-number =  4 -> display-number =  4
index-number =  5 -> display-number =  none
index-number =  6 -> display-number =  5
index-number =  7 -> display-number =  6
index-number =  8 -> display-number =  7
index-number =  9 -> display-number =  8
index-number = 10 -> display-number =  none
etc...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task is exotic enough, that your decision could to be fair enough for accomplishing it. It's simplifying it enough, yet nobody except you will understand it.

I'd suggest just adding a comment to it. However, there are plenty of other ways, which I cannot say they are more elegant, but maybe are more self-explanatory.

```
$counter = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i < 21; $i++) {
    $displayNum = $counter;
    if ($i % 5 == 0) {
        $counter--;
        $displayNum = "none";
    }
    echo "index-number = $i -> display-number = $displayNum <br/>";
    $counter++;
}
```

Will result into:

```
index-number = 1 -> display-number = 1 
index-number = 2 -> display-number = 2 
index-number = 3 -> display-number = 3 
index-number = 4 -> display-number = 4 
index-number = 5 -> display-number = none 
index-number = 6 -> display-number = 5 
index-number = 7 -> display-number = 6 
index-number = 8 -> display-number = 7 
index-number = 9 -> display-number = 8 
index-number = 10 -> display-number = none 
index-number = 11 -> display-number = 9 
index-number = 12 -> display-number = 10 
index-number = 13 -> display-number = 11 
index-number = 14 -> display-number = 12 
index-number = 15 -> display-number = none 
index-number = 16 -> display-number = 13 
index-number = 17 -> display-number = 14 
index-number = 18 -> display-number = 15 
index-number = 19 -> display-number = 16 
index-number = 20 -> display-number = none
```

If you try to minify it with ternary operator, you will end up with code just like yours, which is crypt, rather than explanatory.

You can skip the iteration with `continue` and adding the desired output before that. The very same result can be achieved by:

```
$counter = 1;
for ($i = 1; $i < 21; $i++) {
    if ($i % 5 == 0) {
        echo "index-number = $i -> display-number = none <br/>";
        continue; // more explanatory for SKIP THIS ITERATION
    }
    echo "index-number = $i -> display-number = $counter <br/>";
    $counter++;
}
```

This way you will print `none` and will skip the execution of the iteration, thus `$counter` will not increment, and on 6-th iteration it will be 5.

Comment: thanks for your answer and suggestions. Each participant answers 4 questions and one bonus-question per day. Therefore the 'count' of the participant is retrieved from another FEU-table, and stored each time the 5 questions are answered. When a participant's 'count' is f.i. 40, question 40 is shown but displayed as 'question 32' That's why i have to calculate the display-number, in this case (ceil((40/5) * 4). Another solution would be to increment and store the 'count' by 1 each time 5 questions have been answered. That way i could just retrieve the 'count' and multipy by 5.

Comment: Couldn't your table has flags - for normal questions count and for bonus questions count, thus if a participant answer all 5 questions, you will know that he answered 4 normal and 1 bonus. When 8 days in a row he answers 4+1 questions, you will have 8*4=32 count for normal questions stored in DB and 8*1 = 8 count stored for special questions. This way, you will know the exact number of question you want to show to the end user retrieved from the database, instead of calculated via a strange formula :)

Comment: Flags could work, however i'm not permitted to change anything about any table or store anything other than this count and answers given. Unfortunately i cannot increase the count by 1 per each 5 questions, since other scripts from other applications need to use that count for other purposes. So i'm stuck with this 'count' that is stored in some FEU-system, retrieve the 5 questions starting with that count, and  then change it into a display-number in the interface. Using ceil however seems dirty, that's why i wonder if there's a neater way.

Comment: The other ways, I have posted, are not more elegant. If you want to be self-explanatory with the code, here it is - you should use modulus, do the math `$i % == 0; 40 questions; 8 special; Display num = All questions - Special Questions`. You can achieve by several algorithms, all I assume worse variation than database store, but since you cannot change the database, you cannot achieve maximum elegance :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if($i % 5 != 0) {
  // do your stuff
}
else {
  // skipped
}
```

according to expected output:-

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 101; $i++) {
    echo 'index-number = '. $i.' -> display-number ='. (($i % 5 != 0) ? $i : 'none').'<br>';  
}
```

output :-

```
index-number = 1 -> display-number =1
index-number = 2 -> display-number =2
index-number = 3 -> display-number =3
index-number = 4 -> display-number =4
index-number = 5 -> display-number =none
index-number = 6 -> display-number =6
index-number = 7 -> display-number =7
index-number = 8 -> display-number =8
index-number = 9 -> display-number =9
index-number = 10 -> display-number =none
and so on....
```

Comment: Damn, you beat me to it!

Comment: I'm probably not asking this in a clear way, sorry for that. Modulus would work if i had to know if the index-number was a 5th question. But when i get the index-number of the question i need to convert it to a display number that does something like this:

    (ceil(($i/5) * 4)

Comment: @ben, so if $i = 10; then ceil(10/5)*4 is 8 ... do you want to know if 8 is fifth iteration? I guess not?

Comment: @Royal Bg, 
if $i = 10 then i know i have to replace it by  8 / 
if $i = 33 then i know i have to replace it by 27 / 
if $i = 50 then i know i have to replace it by 40 / 
 (ceil(($i/5) * 4) does what i want, but i wondered if there's a cleaner way i writing that

Comment: @Ben, But why do you want to replace, whats the overall point? You have 100 questions in the DB, what's the problem when iterating through the resultset, after each fifth iteration (with modulus) instead of fetching the next row, fetch a bonus question?

Comment: So question 3 will be numbered as 3, 4 as 4, since 5 is a bonus question it will not be numbered, and question number 6 is numbered as 5, right?

Comment: @Tom, exactly, as i tried to show in the edit of my question. (ceil(($i/5) * 4) does just that, but i wonder if there are other ways to accomplish this.

Comment: `$counter = $i; if ($i % 5 == 0) { //bonus question $counter--; } else { //here $counter will be 5 again, after you are on sixth iteration }` something like that (you will need some more configuration), but why? Why do you number a bonus question this way? You will have once (10/5)*4 = 8 bonus question and once 8/5*4 = 8 - not bonus question?

Comment: @RakeshSharma, thanks but that way there'd be a gap in the numbering. You'd skip from question 4 to question 6.

Comment: @Ben so you want to use both values in other variable and use them outside loop?